# How to observe html5 audio/video events on mobile safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I'm writing some javascript to play remote audio files. I want the playing to start only after the file is ready to be played. Tried observing the `canplay` event or observing the ready state of the audio element (see code below). Both work in desktop browsers but neither works in mobile browsers on iPhone (safari and chrome). I suspect the mobile browsers on iPhone do not support these media events. Is there a workaround to allow files to play only when ready on mobile?

This doesn't work on mobile safari:

```
this.audio.oncanplay = () => {
  that.audio.play();
};
```

This doesn't work either:

```
this.audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
  if(that.audio.readyState == 4) {
    that.audio.play();
  }
})
```